# How to change Images in a custom photo gallary smoothly following the finger movement

Tags: android, animation, photo-gallery

I have  a custom photo gallary app which shows images from a specific folder. 
what is not clear to me is how to navigate between images smoothly following the finger movement, like this:

[image]

As seen by touching the display and moving to left, current image moves also corresponds to the finger movement and depending on where finger is up, current photo is stayed or replaced by the next photo (I hope image is clear enough!).

Could anybody please explain me how to make this effect?

I have tested ImageSwitcher but it is not how I want: in onTouch() method, I can detect the gesture (moving to left or right) and using a proper animation change images, but it is not possible to smoothly follow the finger movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might not want to try it because you have already done some work on your implementation, but :

The easiest way is to use a ViewPager that handles the scroll (and creates/deletes views when needed) and just override the default transformation with a [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html).

Comment: I have currently use a custom extension of ImageView which is zoomable. it seems that it is possible to still use this custom ImageView inside the ViewPager, isn't it?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. You'll just have to make sure that your implementation doesn't break the ViewPager by preventing the touch event propagation. But you can always find another library like this one : https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView